# I have a java code that requires some class from dll's so how can I refer them

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, jar

I am using eclipse IDE. In that I have a java code that requires some classes in dll so how can I add dll files in the code please guide.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a function in a DLL directly. You have to use a piece of Java technology called [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) that does the bridging between Java and the 3rd party DLL. There are tools that can make this bridging for you easier, but with a bit of effort and some C/C++ knowledge, for example, you are able to do this for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a DLL from inside Eclipse, you either need to include the DLL in a location on the system PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Also there is another way is

you need to explicitly specify the java.library.path property in the run configuration of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Loading the DLL is only the easiest step.

As it is not really trivial to call a method of a DLL from Java this answer is only a summary of hints what you have to do to call a function from a DLL. The whole story would fill a book. And in fact there are several books about JNI (Java Native Interface).

To call a function in a native library you have to declare a method in your java class as native with the java keyword native. The declaration of this method must not have a body.

The name of the function exported from your DLL must match the following pattern: Java_classname_methodname where classname is the name of the class where you declared the native method methodname.

For example if you declare a native method private native void sayHello() in your class MyClass the name of the DLL's function would be: Java_MyClass_sayHello

Also keep in mind that the function must be exported from the DLL with the correct calling conventions JNIEXPORT and JNICALL which are defined in the header file jni.h that comes with your JDK (see include folder)

Every function of a DLL to be called from Java also must have two "hidden" arguments as first parameters (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj). env is a pointer to the calling JVM which allows you callback into the JVM and obj is the object from which the method was called.

So the whole definition of the DLL's method in our example would be: JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_sayHello(JNIEnv *, jobject);

Due to these restrictions of JNI a DLL called from your code must be specifially made for your code. To use an arbitrary DLL from Java you usually have to create an adapting DLL with the conventions of JNI that itself loads the "target" DLL and calls the required functions.

To generate the correct headers for your adapter DLL you can use the tool javah shipped with the JDK. This tool will generate the headers to be implemented from your Java code.

For further information the documentation of JNI will cover all questions about interaction with the JVM from native code. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

Answer (score 0):

Demo Program

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLong;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.*;

public class Main {

public interface simpleDLL extends Library {
    simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL)Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows()? "simpleDLL" : "simpleDLLLinuxPort"),simpleDLL.class);

    byte giveVoidPtrGetChar(Pointer param); // char giveVoidPtrGetChar(void* param);
    int giveVoidPtrGetInt(Pointer param);   //int giveVoidPtrGetInt(void* param);
    int giveIntGetInt(int a);               // int giveIntGetInt(int a);
    void simpleCall();                      // void simpleCall();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    simpleDLL sdll = simpleDLL.INSTANCE;

    sdll.simpleCall();  // call of void function

    int a = 3;
    int result1 = sdll.giveIntGetInt(a);  // calling function with int parameter&result
    System.out.println("giveIntGetInt("+a+"): " + result1);

    String testStr = "ToBeOrNotToBe";
    Memory mTest = new Memory(testStr.length()+1);  // '+1' remember about extra byte for \0 character!
    mTest.setString(0, testStr);
    String testReturn = mTest.getString(0); // you can see that String got properly stored in Memory object
    System.out.println("String in Memory:"+testReturn);

    Memory intMem = new Memory(4);  // allocating space
    intMem.setInt(0, 666); // setting allocated memory to an integer
    Pointer intPointer = intMem.getPointer(0);

    int int1 = sdll.giveVoidPtrGetInt(Pointer.NULL); // passing null, getting default result
    System.out.println("giveVoidPtrGetInt(null):" + int1); // passing int stored in Memory object, getting it back
    int int2 = sdll.giveVoidPtrGetInt(intMem);
   //int int2 = sdll.giveVoidPtrGetInt(intPointer);  causes JVM crash, use memory object directly!
    System.out.println("giveVoidPtrGetInt(666):" + int2);

    byte char1 = sdll.giveVoidPtrGetChar(Pointer.NULL);  // passing null, getting default result
    byte char2 = sdll.giveVoidPtrGetChar(mTest);        // passing string stored in Memory object, getting first letter

    System.out.println("giveVoidPtrGetChar(null):" + (char)char1);
    System.out.println("giveVoidPtrGetChar('ToBeOrNotToBe'):" + (char)char2);

}
```

}